# Time complexity of Rectangle Covering algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, greedy

I have a task to submit on greedy algorithms. I wrote this code but I'm not sure what the time complexity of the algorithm is. This problem called "Rectangle Covering".

This is the code:

```
MinGreedyCutReg(R[])
    cut[] = null
    while R != null
        endIndex = 0
        for i = 0 to R.length-1
            if(endIndex < R[i].r)
                endIndex = R[i].r
        maxCount = 0
        maxIndex = 0
        for i = 0 to endIndex
            updateMax = 0
            for j = 0 to R.length - 1
                if(R[j].l <= i and R[j].r >= i)
                    updateMax++
            if(updateMax > maxCount):
                maxCount = updateMax
                maxIndex = i
        cut.add(maxIndex)
        for i = 0 to R.length - 1
            if(R[i].l <= maxIndex and R[i].r >= maxIndex)
                R.remove(i)
    return cut
```

I am trying to find the time complexity of the algorithm. I think it is O(n * m) because of the nested loop. My friend tells me it is O(n^2) due to this nested loop. So basically I think the question is what time the nested loops can do and why.

Comment: Please use full words for variables, attributes and function. This alongside comments would really help us read and understand your code. Also explain the problem you are solving, don't make us research it : the question should be self-sufficient

Comment: What is `n` and `m` in `O(n*m)` (your evalutation of the time complexity) ?

Comment: `R.remove(i)` looks suspicious. In most programming languages your loop would then skip an entry making this algorithm wrong. The `return cutMinGreedyCutReg(R[])` in the middle of your function's code, will *end* the execution of the function, making the rest below it *dead code*. Before discussing time complexity, you need to ensure the algorithm does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: You also need to explain the structure of R to include what is meant by ```R[i]```